# r image function change size

Tags: r, image, text-formatting

I'm trying to visualize a matrix using image function. I'd like to set the size of cells (I mean the small squares each of which represents one elements of the matrix). I don't know how many elements will my matrix have beforehand.

This is my code now:

```
A <- matrix(1:20, 5, 4)
image(A)
```

and I'd like to have something like this:

```
image(A, sizeOfCell=10)
```

Would anyone have some idea?

Comment: A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be very helpful to illustrate your problem. At the time you call `image()`, surely you must have some matrix with some know dimension. Why is a specific size required? Are you during further manipulation after?

Answer (score 1):

grid units are probably easiest to work with,

```
A <- matrix(1:20, 5, 4)
library(grid)
m = A/max(A) # replace with matrix of colours, this will default to grey
grid.raster(m, 
            width = unit(NROW(A)*5,"mm"), # cell 5mm wide
            height = unit(NCOL(A)*4,"mm"),# and 4mm high
            interpolate = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.  It works but I d need to:
1) not to be dependent on number of rows and columns
2) to be albe set the columns by myself like this
`loc1g <- c(0, 1, 2, 0)
loc2g <- c(1,1, 2, 0)
loc3g <- c(0, 1, 2, 0)
pval <- data.frame(loc1g, loc2g, loc3g)
x = 1:ncol(pval)
y = 1:nrow(pval)

image(x, y, t(as.matrix(pval)),
      col = c('white', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green'),
      breaks = c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2),
      xaxt='n', 
      yaxt='n', 
      ylim=c(max(y)+0.5, min(y)-0.5), 
      xlab='', 
      ylab='',
)`
Would it be able to modify it to fulfil these conditions?